Should these two questions be combined?
lemonginger asked What happens when I make a typo?,
and I also added the question Can a transaction be reversed? since it's fundamental to the bitcoin network.
Is it desirable to combine these questions since lemonginger asks in passing if she/he can get back typo-ed coins?  Or are they different enough that they are worth keeping, based on the likelihood that users will search differently to find solutions to these two problems?

They are different questions, in spite of having similar answers. One is about what happens when you mistype an address (which is probably not going to work because of checksums) and the other is about whether or not transactions can be reversed (they can't because of bitcoin's nature).
I vote to keep them separated.
